# Can I install Windows 7 onto a Virtual PC on a Windows XP computer?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

My computer is running Windows XP. I want to test some software on Windows 7. Can I run Windows 7 in Virtual PC on an XP computer?

Thanks!

EDIT: The reason I ask is that the documentation for Virtual PC 2007 does NOT mention Windows 7 as a supported guest operating system.

Comment: It worked well as delenda suggested - attaching the ISO as a virtual CD drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, fire up VirtualBox, VMWare or VirtualPC and attach the ISO to a virtual CD drive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's what its made for.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to install Windows 7 RC using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, don't use a version older than [Virtual PC 2007 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28c97d22-6eb8-4a09-a7f7-f6c7a1f000b5&displaylang=en) (6.0.192.0). Old version (6.0.156.0) will surprise you with BSOD after installation of the Virtual Machine Additions (Error: Fs_Rec.sys - The driver mistakenly marked a part of its image pagable instead of nonpagable.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. It doesn't matter which host operation system you are using. As long as you have one of the virtual programs running, you should be able to run Windows 7 on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports it, you can even install 64bit Windows 7 on a 32bit XP host using virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

I am running XP Pro SP3 on a Dell Latitude E6500.  Inside of that I am running VirtualBox with Windows7.

Most everything works well.  I am unable to view Win7 in full screen and I havent found drivers for my sound card yet...but other than that I am pleased.